# Shinyjs: On click option in shiny dashboard

Tags: shiny, shinydashboard, shinyjs

I have a shiny dashboard app with 3 tabs and a notification menu. I am trying to track user activity on the dashboard and wish to log each of their clicks on the dashboard.

The code in server.R for the tabset panel is as below:

```
output$tabs1=renderUI(
    tabsetPanel(type="tab",
                tabPanel(id="OverallTab","Overall Activity"),
                tabPanel(id="Tab1","Tab 1 details"),
                tabPanel(id="Tab2","Tab 2 details"))
```

Part of my notification code is as below:

```
output$notiMenu <- renderMenu({
            all_nots <- apply(u_notd, 1, function(row) {
              notificationItem(text = row[["notification"]], icon("users"))
            })
            dropdownMenu(type = "notifications", .list = all_nots)
          })
```

I am trying to use shinyjs to write to a dataframe if a user clicks on either of the tabs or notification menu as below:

```
  tab1_clicled=""
  tab2_clicked=""
  noti_clicked=""
  shinyjs::onclick("notiMenu",print("Notification clicked"),noti_clicked="YES")
  shinyjs::onclick("Tab1",print("Tab1 clicked"),tab1_clicled="YES")
  shinyjs::onclick("Tab2", print("Tab2 clicked"),tab2_clicled="YES")
  df=as.data.frame(tab1_clicked,tab2_clicked,noti_clicked)
```

I face 2 issues here,

1) the on click option doesn't appear to work for the tab panels, using the shinyjs reference([here](https://github.com/daattali/shinyjs)), I see that there is only a mention of using on click for the tabset panel and not for each tab panel?

2) I'm unable to modify the value of tab1_clicked inside the onclick function. It throws an error saying:  Unhandled error in observer: unused argument (tab1_clicled = "YES")

Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just quickly skimmed your code and I can see two errors. The first parameter of `onclick` is the ID of the element. In your case, you want the ID of the actual tab button, but unfortunately the way tabs work in shiny, "Tab1" is actually the ID of the container of the tab panel but it's not the id of the tab button itself.  Look at the HTML of a shiny app and you'll see that. Tabs are a bit weird and annoying and it's really difficult to deal with the tab buttons themselves in shiny.

Secondly, The second argument of `onclick` is the expression, but you're trying to run two expressions `print("Tab1 clicked")` and `tab1_clicled="YES"`. You need to wrap these in `{}` so that it's considered one expression, like this:

`onclick(id, {print("Tab1 clicked"); tab1_clicled="YES"}`

But unfortunately getting the id of the tab button is difficult so I don't think `onclick` will be useful for that

Comment: Thanks @daattali, It fixes the issue with tracking when a user clicks on a notification but still leaves me hanging on being able to track if a user clicked on a tab. I know you mentioned that a way to do this would be to write a piece of line like input$Tabs1 but I don't know what to put on the RHS of that condition. In vain I tried if (input$tabs1==TRUE) then tab1_clicked="YES". But clearly this doesn't work. Any suggestion? Appreciate the help.

Comment: I don't think I understand what you're doing, or maybe you don't understand what my answer was?  If you want something to happen when a tab is selected, you don't need to use `onclick`, you can just listen for the reactive event triggered by the tabset input.  If you have a navbarPage for example with id of "navbar" and you have two tabs with ids "tab1" and "tab2", then you can have an `observe({ print(input$navbar) })` and it would print "tab1" when you open tab1 and "tab2" when you open tab2. Experiment with that.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Thanks again. You are a great help @daattali