# Shinyjs: How to detect if a user clicked on a tab?

Tags: shiny, shinydashboard, shinyjs

I want to track users journey in a Shiny app and for that I need to detect if a user clicked on a tab. For that I’m using `shinyjs` library and a custom js tracking function. But currently I can’t come up how to use `input$tabs` instead of `id` in `onclick()` function. When I use `tabName` of a tab as `id` the function doesn’t react on a click.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinyjs)

ui = dashboardPage(

    dashboardHeader(title = "Shiny"),

    dashboardSidebar(
      sidebarMenu(id = "tabs",

        menuItem("Section_1", tabName = "section_1", icon = icon("align-justify"), 
                 startExpanded = TRUE, selected = TRUE,
                 menuSubItem("Subsection 1", tabName = "report_1", selected = TRUE),
                 menuSubItem("Subsection 2", tabName = "report_2")),
        menuItem("Section_2", tabName = "section_2", icon = icon("align-justify"))

        )
      ),

    dashboardBody(

      useShinyjs(),

      tabItems(
        tabItem("report_1", h1(id = "a", "a")),
        tabItem("report_2", h1(id = "b", "b")),
        tabItem("section_2", h1(id = "c", "c")))
      )
    )


server <- function(input, output, session) {

  onclick("report_1", alert("tab = report_1"))
  onclick("report_2", alert("tab = report_2"))
  onclick("section_2", alert("tab = section_2"))

  onclick("a", alert("tab = report_1"))
  onclick("b", alert("tab = report_2"))
  onclick("c", alert("tab = section_2"))

}

shinyApp(ui=ui, server=server)
```

Answer (score 4):

Thanks to that [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33661227/8792403) I have found the solution to my question. There is no need to use `onclick()` function at all.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinyjs)

ui = dashboardPage(

    dashboardHeader(title = "Shiny"),

    dashboardSidebar(
      sidebarMenu(id = "tabs",

        menuItem("Section_1", tabName = "section_1", icon = icon("align-justify"), 
                 startExpanded = TRUE, selected = TRUE,
                 menuSubItem("Subsection 1", tabName = "report_1", selected = TRUE),
                 menuSubItem("Subsection 2", tabName = "report_2")),
        menuItem("Section_2", tabName = "section_2", icon = icon("align-justify"))

        )
      ),

    dashboardBody(

      useShinyjs(),

      tabItems(
        tabItem("report_1", h1(id = "a", "a")),
        tabItem("report_2", h1(id = "b", "b")),
        tabItem("section_2", h1(id = "c", "c")))
      )
    )


server <- function(input, output, session) {

  observe({ 

    if(input$tabs == "report_1") {
      alert("tab = report_1")
    } else if(input$tabs == "report_2"){
      alert("tab = report_2")
    } else {
      alert("tab = section_2")
    }

  })
}

shinyApp(ui=ui, server=server)
```